# Who stole control+Q in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't work, in all applications.  It used to be the "Quit" command in most applications (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> still works OK), even in other applications which use it differently, it has no effect.  All applications behave as if nothing was typed.

I suspect that something grabs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for its own use before the applications see it, at the window manager or X11 level; I tried to look through every settings menu and configuration file I could find, but could not find what does it.

Did anyone else encounter the same problem (and hopefully found a solution)?

Thanks

Comment: I do not experience this issue. In contrast, I intentionally grab the key in Settings - Keyboard to prevent me from closing an application if I just wanted to close a tab or a window with Ctrl+w

Comment: It is working for me with Ubuntu 18.04.. You can add shortcuts by: opening **Settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboards**, then scroll down and add the shortcut you want.

Comment: To check "who stole that" you can use search option under *Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard*

Comment: As I said, I have already looked through any keyboard settings I could find, and none uses Control-Q.  I tried setting "Close Window" to Control-Q, but this did not help, all it did is that Alt-F4 stopped working too.